# Definition content first characters skipping to numbering box

Tags: tcolorbox, theorems

I have the following issue of first sentence characters skipping to numbering box :

Like the **O** in Defintion 1.6.2

The text start with : " On appelle " which explains the origin of displayed charachters.

[image]

The used environment :

```
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{theorems}
    \newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{Definition}{Definition}{
        colback=orange!5,
        colframe=orange!35!black,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        enhanced,
        sharp corners,
        attach boxed title to top left={xshift=3mm, yshift=-2mm},
        boxed title style={size=small, colframe=orange!35!black},
        separator sign none,
        before lower={\par\noindent}, % Ensure content starts on a new line
    }{def}


\begin{document}

\begin{Definition}[Lien complet]
On appelle lien complet, ou complete linkage, la distance entre deux clusters définie par:
$$
d_{\text {complet }}\left(\mathcal{C}_{k}, \mathcal{C}_{l}\right)=\max _{(\vec{u}, \vec{v}) \in \mathcal{C}_{k} \times \mathcal{C}_{l}} d(\vec{u}, \vec{v}) .
$$
Une approche intermédiaire consiste à considérer la distance moyenne entre un élément du premier cluster et un élément du deuxième. C'est le lien moyen.
\end{Definition}

\begin{Definition}[Lien moyen]
On appelle lien moyen, ou average linkage, la distance entre deux clusters définie par:
$$
d_{\text {moyen }}\left(\mathcal{C}_{k}, \mathcal{C}_{l}\right)=\frac{1}{\left|\mathcal{C}_{k}\right|} \frac{1}{\left|\mathcal{C}_{l}\right|} \sum_{\vec{u} \in \mathcal{C}_{k}} \sum_{\vec{v} \in \mathcal{C}_{l}} d(\vec{u}, \vec{v})
$$
Cette distance est aussi parfois appelée UPGMA pour Unweighted Paired Group Method with Arithmetic mean.

\end{Definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please read up on whart `\newtcbtheorem` generates. The env takes a mandatory argument in `{}`, as you did not give any it takes the first letter.

Comment: Unrelated `d_{\text{moyen}}` does not do what you think it does. You might want to use `\mathrm` or `\textup` instead of `\text`. Why Try this `\textit{text $\text{text}$}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of your definition is

```
\begin{Definition}{Insert the title here}{label}
...
\end{Definition}
```

If you want a definition without title, you can leave the `{}` empty, but you cannot write the definition without it. Same for the label.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{Definition}{Definition}{
    colback=orange!5,
    colframe=orange!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    enhanced,
    sharp corners,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=3mm, yshift=-2mm},
    boxed title style={size=small, colframe=orange!35!black},
    separator sign none,
    before lower={\par\noindent}, % Ensure content starts on a new line
}{def}

\begin{document}

\begin{Definition}{Title}{label}
On appelle lien complet, ou complete linkage, la distance entre deux clusters définie par:
\[
d_{\text {complet }}\left(\mathcal{C}_{k}, \mathcal{C}_{l}\right)=\max _{(\vec{u}, \vec{v}) \in \mathcal{C}_{k} \times \mathcal{C}_{l}} d(\vec{u}, \vec{v}) .
\]
Une approche intermédiaire consiste à considérer la distance moyenne entre un élément du premier cluster et un élément du deuxième. C'est le lien moyen.
\end{Definition}

\begin{Definition}{}{AnotherLabel}
On appelle lien moyen, ou average linkage, la distance entre deux clusters définie par:
\[
d_{\text {moyen }}\left(\mathcal{C}_{k}, \mathcal{C}_{l}\right)=\frac{1}{\left|\mathcal{C}_{k}\right|} \frac{1}{\left|\mathcal{C}_{l}\right|} \sum_{\vec{u} \in \mathcal{C}_{k}} \sum_{\vec{v} \in \mathcal{C}_{l}} d(\vec{u}, \vec{v})
\]
Cette distance est aussi parfois appelée UPGMA pour Unweighted Paired Group Method with Arithmetic mean.
\end{Definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "*If you want a Definition with title*" should probably be "*If you want a Definition without title*".

Comment: @campa Indeed! Thx!

Comment: yes , this is exactly what i just tried. 

For curiosity , what is the difference between title and label in \begin{Definition}{Title}{label} ?

Comment: @TouMou The label is the key used to reference the definition, e.g. if you want to use `\ref{label}` somewhere in your text to link to the theorem. You should NOT use the complete title for this. Avoid special characters like spaces in labels.

Answer (score 0):

Just add title for each definition and issue will be solved :

```
   \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{theorems}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins}
    \newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{Definition}{Definition}{
        colback=orange!5,
        colframe=orange!35!black,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        enhanced,
        sharp corners,
        attach boxed title to top left={xshift=3mm, yshift=-2mm},
        boxed title style={size=small, colframe=orange!35!black},
        separator sign none,
        before lower={\par\noindent}, % Ensure content starts on a new line
    }{def}


\begin{document}

\begin{Definition}{lien complet}{}
On appelle lien complet, ou complete linkage, la distance entre deux clusters définie par:
$$
d_{\text {complet }}\left(\mathcal{C}_{k}, \mathcal{C}_{l}\right)=\max _{(\vec{u}, \vec{v}) \in \mathcal{C}_{k} \times \mathcal{C}_{l}} d(\vec{u}, \vec{v}) .
$$
Une approche intermédiaire consiste à considérer la distance moyenne entre un élément du premier cluster et un élément du deuxième. C'est le lien moyen.
\end{Definition}

\begin{Definition}{lien moyen}{}
On appelle lien moyen, ou average linkage, la distance entre deux clusters définie par:
$$
d_{\text {moyen }}\left(\mathcal{C}_{k}, \mathcal{C}_{l}\right)=\frac{1}{\left|\mathcal{C}_{k}\right|} \frac{1}{\left|\mathcal{C}_{l}\right|} \sum_{\vec{u} \in \mathcal{C}_{k}} \sum_{\vec{v} \in \mathcal{C}_{l}} d(\vec{u}, \vec{v})
$$
Cette distance est aussi parfois appelée UPGMA pour Unweighted Paired Group Method with Arithmetic mean.

\end{Definition}
\end{document}
```

This displays something like :

[image]

Comment: You are missing the `skins` tcb library. Without it, you cannot use the `enhanced` option.

Comment: I added \tcbuselibrary{skins}

Comment: Please also remove the full title from the labels. Things like spaces are really not that good of an idea in labels...

Comment: is it Ok now , or shoud i replace \begin{Definition}{lien moyen}{} by \begin{Definition}{lien moyen}

Comment: `\begin{Definition}{lien moyen}` would be wrong. You must not leave out mandatory arguments. That's exactly the problem in your question. Instead of leaving it empty, choose a short key which is easy to remember and allows you to reference your theorem.